# Given a json string, convert the nested json string into a key value pairs, with the key being the name of the element hierarchy appended with “_”

Tags: json, string

Given a json string, convert the nested json string into a key value pairs, with the key being the name of the element hierarchy appended with “_”.

```
{
  "person": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": {
      "first": "John",
      "middle": "H",
      "last": "Doe"
    },
    "address": {
      "home": {
        "line1": "test address line 1",
        "line2": "test address line 1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
Output: 
[
  "person_id"= 1,
  "person_name_first"="John",
  "person_name_middle"= "H",
  "person_name_last"= "Doe",
  "person_address_home_line1"="test address line 1",
  "person_address_home_line2"="test address line 1"
]
```

Comment: Hi there, please add more detail in your question so that someone else in the future who reviews your question is able to understand it too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively look for each key and generate your object.

```js
const obj = { "person": { "id": 1, "name": { "first": "John", "middle": "H", "last": "Doe" }, "address": { "home": { "line1": "test address line 1", "line2": "test address line 1" } } } };
const generatePaths = (obj, prefix = "") => {
  let o = {};
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => {
     const key = prefix ? prefix + '_' + k : k;
     if(typeof v === 'object' && !!v){
        const par = generatePaths(v, key);
        o = {...o, ...par};
     } else {
      o[key] = v;
     }
  });
  return o;
}
console.log(generatePaths(obj));
```